# Propensity Score Matching with few treated observations

Tags: matching, propensity-scores

Consider the situation in which one has 3000 untreated observations and 30 treated observations, that is, a ratio of 1/100 between treated and untread. In this situation, I believe the logistical or the probit regression tends to produce propensity scores close to zero for the untreated observations and then it produces a considerable bias to the matching process. In this situation, with few treated observations, what is the usual way to overcome this problem of the propensity score being inadequate?

Comment: Is the issue the 1:100 ratio, or is it that there are only 30 observations in one category (hence overfitting, complete separation and other issues)? I guess, if you explanatory variables are not that good for explaining the treatment assignment all propensity score might be around 1/100 - but is it a problem per-se if the propensity scores are low? I guess it is only an issue if there is a complete separation between treatment groups in propensity scores (as could happen when there's severe overfitting).

Comment: Why do you have to use propensity score matching, you could do clustering and grouping or use brute force approach

Comment: R-squared is higher than 0.5, so I do think the independent variables explain reasonably well the binary dependent variable. As for other methods you mentioned, forecaster, I'm not familiar with them and it might help if you showed them to me.

Comment: Match with replacement?